# Stage3D Agal Anti-Aliasing

Tags: actionscript-3, agal

I created an engine which draws 2D planes in the Stage3D API in Actionscript 3. And my question is, how do I turn all anti-aliasing off, because when I scale it all the pixels get really blurry, and I'm trying to use pixel-art for this.

This is the code I use:

```
protected function setupShaders() {
        var vertexShaderAssembler:AGALMiniAssembler = new AGALMiniAssembler();
        vertexShaderAssembler.assemble( Context3DProgramType.VERTEX,
                "dp4 op.x, va0, vc0 \n"+
                "dp4 op.y, va0, vc1 \n"+
                "mov op.z, vc2.z    \n"+
                "mov op.w, vc3.w    \n"+
                "mov v0, va1.xy     \n"+
                "mov v0.z, va0.z    \n");

        var fragmentShaderAssembler:AGALMiniAssembler = new AGALMiniAssembler();
        fragmentShaderAssembler.assemble( Context3DProgramType.FRAGMENT,
                "tex ft0, v0, fs0 <2d,clamp,linear, nomip>\n"+
                "mov oc, ft0 \n");

        shader = context3D.createProgram();
        shader.upload(vertexShaderAssembler.agalcode, fragmentShaderAssembler.agalcode);
    }

public function draw() {

        context3D.setProgram(shader);
        context3D.setBlendFactors(Context3DBlendFactor.ONE, Context3DBlendFactor.ONE_MINUS_SOURCE_ALPHA);
        context3D.setProgramConstantsFromMatrix(Context3DProgramType.VERTEX, 0, parent.modelViewMatrix, true);
        context3D.setTextureAt(0, sprites.texture);

        if (updateVBOs) {
            vertexBuffer = context3D.createVertexBuffer(vertices.length / 3,3);
            indexBuffer = context3D.createIndexBuffer(indices.length);
            uvBuffer = context3D.createVertexBuffer(UVs.length >> 1, 2);
            indexBuffer.uploadFromVector(indices, 0, indices.length);
            uvBuffer.uploadFromVector(UVs, 0, UVs.length >>1);
            updateVBOs = false;
        }

        vertexBuffer.uploadFromVector(vertices, 0, vertices.length / 3);
        context3D.setVertexBufferAt(0, vertexBuffer, 0, Context3DVertexBufferFormat.FLOAT_3);
        context3D.setVertexBufferAt(1, uvBuffer, 0,  Context3DVertexBufferFormat.FLOAT_2);

        context3D.drawTriangles(indexBuffer, 0, nChildren << 1);
    }

public function configureBackBuffer(width:uint, height:uint) {
        context3D.configureBackBuffer( width, height, 0, false);
    }
```

[image: Anti-Aliasing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, instead of `"tex ft0, v0, fs0 <2d, clamp, linear, nomip>\n"` I had to do `"tex ft0, v0, fs0 <2d, clamp, nearest, nomip>\n"`